# Can I travel within the U.S with the length of stay expired?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I'm a refugee and I want to travel to different State, I still have my Visa update but the length of stay is over, all my process are at immigration. What should I do travel?
What documents I'll show at airport?

Comment: Hi and welcome! How do you plan to travel (air, bus, car, train)?

Comment: Can you explain more? Have you overstayed? Have you applied for a change of status?

Comment: What is a "visa update"? And if you are a refugee, why do you have a "length of stay"? What documents do you have? (passport? I-94? EAD?)